# prevent DotNet application to load dlls from the local folder?

Tags: .net, security, secure-coding

is there a way to force the DotNet Framework to load dlls like the "version.dll" from save folders, as system32? 
The "version.dll" for example is loaded automatically and not imported in the source.

I want to prevent, that a DotNet applications tries to load such dlls from the local folder, meaning the folder where the exe is placed.

Best regards